# Magento 2 Custom Validation on Address Book (street[1])

Tags: magento2, customer-address, form-validation

For the checkout screen (custom OneStepCheckout plugin) I managed to succesfully add a custom validation rule on the second street input. Now I'd like to do the same for the default Address Book pages, but I can't seem to figure out where.

The custom rule "housenumber" has been added to the **\Magento_Ui\web\js\lib\validation\rules.js** files within my custom Theme. Preferably I'd like to use this same rule for validation within the edit page (*relative path: /customer/address/edit/id/[XXX]/*).

Unfortunately most information seems to be about the checkout page, not for the additional forms where addresses can be edited.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to take a look at this GitHub module

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-Address-Lines

Mage2 Module Experius AddressLines,

Adds labels to address lines and adds configuration per address line.

Configuration Per Line *(Required Entry Yes/No, Label and Validation Classes)*

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Lines

**This module also works on the Customer Account Address Edit pages and if you enable the Address to Display on the Customer Registration Page it will also show there.**

*For more information how to Display the Address on the Customer Registration Page take a look at this blog article I wrote https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-address-fields-customer-registration/*